# Can I use depmixs4 for multiple subjects?

Tags: r

For example, I have 100 individuals. I have their criminal activities, as well as some other characteristics. I want to build a HMM model so that I can examine how some of their characteristics influence their latent variable transition, and how some other characteristics influence their criminal activities given their latent state. Can I use Depmixs4 for it? If not, do I have other options?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, depmixS4 can be used for multiple subjects. These would be repeated time-series, and you can indicate them through the `ntimes` argument supplied to the `depmix` function. See also `?depmix`